# CSS responsive layout with an image and a side section

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Layout description: image and a side section put in a container called card

The side section is just a container with fixed width of 300px containing some info text, and buttons.

The image should be shown as large as possible, but not more than 100% of the width size (the limit is the width of the view port, the height is unlimited).

If `(image_width + section_width <= viewport_width` the image is shown in full size and the side section is shown to the right of the image.

If `(image_width + section_width > viewport_width` the image is shown above the side section.

In both cases the card is centered horizontally.

I almost achieved this [here](https://codepen.io/sunsande/pen/XWgvdoG), but there are still 2 problems (please use first Chrome or Edge for testing):

**I.** When the `viewport_width < 800px (the width of the image)` the image is takinng the whole available screen width and the side section is nice below it.

When the `viewport_width > 1100px + some small defaultmargin (image+width + sidebar_width)` the image is shown in full size and the sidebar is placed on the right. Both together they are nicely centered horizontally.

When `800px < viewport_width < 1100px` the sidebar stays correctly below the image but there is some space left to the right of the image (the black area on the screenshot below)
[image]

I would like to avoid that and show the image above the side bar just as it is in the case `viewport_width > 1100px` and the width of the card container in this case should have the width of the image and the card should be centered horizontally

Is there a way to acheive that? If you have a solution using `display: grid` or something else I would be glad to learn it. But I think it should be also possible using `flex`.

**II.** The centering in the case `viewport_width > 1100px` works in Chrome and Edge (both version 94.0.*) but not in Mozilla FF. Why is that and how could one correct it?

In Mozilla FF the black area from the screen shot appears between the image and the sidebar and the whole card container is stretched from side to side (not centered in the middle). In other words the card  `width: fit-content;` does not work in FF. Why and how could one correct it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did that already: just click the link in the text `I almost achieved this here, `

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add a width of the image
2. The bellow should work in both

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: silver;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.media {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.media img {
  width: 100%;
}

.media>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="media">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/Curve_of_Nature.jpg/800px-Curve_of_Nature.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Tools</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe atque possimus ad harum, veniam asperiores doloremque. Quod, eius qui? Libero, porro ipsam voluptate corrupti quo atque itaque totam ea quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly the solution. I do not want to scale the image up. I want to show it as original size (if possible) and only scale down if it is too big.
In this solution the card is always 100% width and the image is eventually stretched which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the first question:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  
  border: 2px dashed green;
}

.first {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/Curve_of_Nature.jpg/800px-Curve_of_Nature.jpg" >
  <div class="first">LogaLogaLogaLogaLogaLoga</div>
</div>
```

The answer to the second question (about `fit-content` not working in FF) is also in the example:

in order to work in FF one needs the vendor specific `width: -moz-fit-content;`.